# Equivalent of grep -v with git log pickaxe

Tags: git

Probably a simple question but cannot find the answer for looking. Is there a way to negate a `git log pickaxe` search equivalent to the `grep -v` type

eg I want to find all the commits without a gerrit Change-Id tag

```
git log -SChange-Id <some anti regex match switch>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. What you could do is get a list of commits that have change ID tags, and then remove those commits from the global set of commits and look at the remainder.

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me - thanks :-)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - thanks for fixing my terrible spelling, usually I rely on the compiler :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --not $(git log --format="%H" -S'Change-Id <anti regex>')
```

If you have any other arguments you should duplicate them, one inside that `--not` and one outside, otherwise it might be very slow. Alternatively, use a variable.

(`git rev-list` might have been a neater option for inside the `--not`, but it does not have the `-S` option.